# Why does the Java compiler say my class needs to be defined in a separate file?

Tags: java

This keeps on saying to define it in it's own file.

```
public class MathCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
        double fnum, snum, answer;
        {System.out.println("This is the addition calculator");
        System.out.println("Your first number: ");
        fnum = number.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Your second number: ");
        snum = number.nextDouble();
        answer = fnum + snum;
        System.out.println(answer);
        }
        {System.out.println("This is the subtraction calculator");
        System.out.println("Your first number: ");
        fnum = number.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Your second number: ");
        snum = number.nextDouble();
        answer = fnum - snum;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
        {   System.out.println("This is the multiplication calculator");
        System.out.println("Enter your first number: ");
        fnum = number.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter your second number: ");
        snum = number.nextDouble();
        answer = fnum * snum;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
        {   System.out.println("This is the division calculator: ");
        System.out.println("Enter your first number: ");
        fnum = number.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter your second number: ");
        snum = number.nextDouble();
        answer = fnum / snum;
        System.out.println(answer);}
        System.out.println("What review do you give us from terrible bad ok good and great?");
        answer = number.nextDouble();
        int terrible = 1;
        int bad = 2;
        int ok = 3;
        int good = 4;
        int great = 5;
        {if (answer == terrible);
        System.out.println("I'm sorry, we'll try and improve.");
        }{if (answer == bad);
        System.out.println("Ok, we'll improve a bit more.");
        }{if (answer == ok);
        System.out.println("Thank you for your ok review.");
        }{if (answer == good);
        System.out.println("Why, thank you!");
        }{if (answer == great);
        System.out.println("WOW! THANK YOU SO MUCH!");
        }

    }

}
```

I know this is a really simple code, but if you look at the bottom, can you also tell me why it's printing all five arguments?

Comment: Is the name of your file `MathCalculator.java`?

Comment: Is it in a file with some other stuff, or is it by itself?

Comment: For August's question, yes. For Engineer Dollery's question, it's by itself.

Comment: I've got to ask, who taught you to use that format? Or just who's teaching you?

Answer (score 0):

The semi-colons after the `if` statement ensure that the following statement blocks are always executed

```
if (answer == terrible);
                       ^
```

Simply remove them all

Comment: For some reason, the code runs smoothly, even with errors. However, when I hit the                                           System.out.println("What review do you give us from terrible bad ok good and great?"); It says something different

Answer (score 0):

First, all `public` classes need their own file named after them.  Place your `public` class `MathCalculator` in MathCalculator.java.

Second, remove those semicolons after each `if` condition.  They act as the block for the `if` condition, and the `println` statements after that will always print, because they're not attached to the `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your formatting, your IDE will do this for you.

```
{
    if (answer == terrible); // do nothing
    System.out.println("I'm sorry, we'll try and improve.");
}{
    if (answer == bad); // do nothing
    System.out.println("Ok, we'll improve a bit more.");
 }{
    if (answer == ok); // do nothing
    System.out.println("Thank you for your ok review.");
 }{
    if (answer == good); // do nothing
    System.out.println("Why, thank you!");
 }{
    if (answer == great);
    System.out.println("WOW! THANK YOU SO MUCH!");
 }
```

> For some reason, the code runs smoothly, even with errors. However, when I hit the System.out.println("What review do you give us from terrible bad ok good and great?"); It says something different

Most likely you are running an old version of the code if it's not compiling, or you are using eclipse which allows you to run code which doesn't compile and you get an error at runtime.  I suggest you turn this "feature" off and only run code which compiles.